# An English word, a noun, for a concept/situation/condition a group of men may find themselves in

Tags: word-request, translation

I'm in an unsuccessful so far search for an English word, a noun, for a concept/situation/condition a group of men may find themselves in, having to live, say on a deserted island or in a far-off camp, for quite a long time in utter absence of women. I mean anything synonymous to the somewhat odd word "womanlessness".
Maybe (and more preferably) there're some colloquial/slangy words or expressions to denote the insalubrious state/condition a group of men may have to live in for a long time without any interaction with a single woman?

The example sentence may run like this:

> "In the... [here goes the noun being searched for] ... of the men-only camp, the
> guys were getting crazier and crazier from day to day."

Note: For those who happen to know Russian, the word is "безбабье"; although I doubt that it can be easily, if at all, found in Russian dictionaries even if it is understood by most Russian native speakers.

To keep the answers on the right track, two brief notes are added:

#1 I don't think a total lack of normal sexual activity for a long time is favorable to or promoting health for men, and that's what I meant by insalubrious, not the place they live in or things related to personal hygiene

#2 In the context I have in mind all men are straight, for the Russian word "безбабье" implies "no women among men, as possible and desirable sexual partners" concept.

Comment: The relevant word here is *[situational / enforced] **celibacy*** - which doesn't just mean "womanlessness", because *women can be celibate too* (they just don't usually complain about it as much as men! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a great word.

In the semi-formal style of the example sentence, I don't think you do better than the merely descriptive "absence of women".

In a slangy and rather sexist way there is a phrase "sausage party" or "[sausage fest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sausage_fest)" (I hope you get the allusion).

> Our first stop was Joey's bar. It was kind of a giant sausage fest.
> ([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sausage-fest))

Naturally you should be careful with this kind of slang. It wouldn't be appropriate to refer to (for example) workers on an oil rig as a sausage fest.

Comment: I would be careful with 'sausage fest'; it might suggest that, in the absence of women, the isolated men find a solution for their frustration well-known to prisoners, lumberjacks, etc (unless that is the intention). Whose turn is it to wear the dress this Saturday?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but the best I can think of and too long for a comment.

Consider "monasticism".  That need not be only religious, but it has overtones of asceticism and self denial, not just the absence of women. In your context it might still work.

FYI see https://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/southpacific/thereisnothinlikeadame.htm